# Erosion in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to perform image erosion with OpenCV. I want to do it like this: Suppose I have four different elements

```
S1 = [ 0 1 0, 0 1 0, 0 1 0 ]
S2 = [ 0 0 0, 1 1 1, 0 0 0 ]
S3 = [ 0 0 1, 0 1 0, 1 0 0 ]
S4 = [ 0 1 0, 1 1 1, 0 1 0 ]
```

And I want to perform four different erosions with these elements on original image:

```
E1 = I & S1 
E2 = I & S2 
E3 = I & S3
E4 = I & S4
```

where "I" is the original image, and I used "&" to denote erosion for simplicity. Then I want to obtain the final erosion with the addition of these four:

```
E = E1 + E2 + E3 + E4
```

But when implementing these with opencv, I've encountered difficulties in early stages. I declared the elements like this:

```
int S1[3][3] = { { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 } };
int S2[3][3] = { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };
int S3[3][3] = { { 0, 0, 1 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 1, 0, 0 } }; 
int S4[3][3] = { { 0, 1, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 1, 0 } };
```

Then for using "cv::erode" I have difficulties with these elements since they are not the acceptable type. How can I use these elements to obtain my desired erosion mentioned above? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably need to create a `cv::Mat` from your desired kernel shapes, these are known as Structuring elements, and OpenCV provides the [getStructuringElement](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=getstr#Mat%20getStructuringElement%28int%20shape,%20Size%20ksize,%20Point%20anchor%29) function to create a few common shapes.

Alternatively, you can form your own by creating a new matrix from your data directly using something like:

```
cv::Mat S1 = (cv::Mat_<uchar>(3,3) << 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

You can confirm whether this is correct by displaying it in the terminal:

```
std::cout << S1 << std::endl;
```

Once you've found your matrices, they can also be easily combined by simple arithmetic operations such as:

```
cv::Mat E = E1 + E2 + E3 + E4;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did it as you suggested, and it gives out an error saying "Assersion failed (_kernel.type() == CV_8U) in unkown function".

Comment: Aha, I missed it. Now it works, thank you again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)-oject as your kernel. [InputArray](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=inputarray#inputarray) and [OutputArray](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=inputarray#outputarray) (see the [erode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode) docu) can either be Mats or std::vector objects in most cases.

I think you could initialize it like this (not tested):

```
int S1[3][3] = { { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 } };
Mat mat1 = Mat(3, 3, CV_32SC1, S1);
```

Comment: I've tested it, and it gives out an error, I think the type "int" is the problem part. I will look for fixing it. Thank you also for your answer.